# Azure powershell script for delivering logs information

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-monitoring, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I'm using some Azure service and would like to monitor the status of all its connections.

Since log analytics doesn't give me the appropriate metrics to monitor / watch the connection status, I need to develop my own powershell script (with azure CLI) to retrieve the required information.

Where can i execute this powershell script on schedule in order to deliver the latest status information to log analytics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where can i execute this powershell script on schedule in order to deliver the latest status information to log analytics?

To run PowerShell Commands on a regular time/ Schedule:

- You can use Azure Automation Accounts:

For Scheduling, you can use Schedules and create a schedule:

[image]

Then you can run your PowerShell script in Runbook after Creating it.

[image]

After creating in runbook:

[image]

Here i have given sample code, you can typr your powershell script here.

Output:

[image]

For Further you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/automation-tutorial-runbook-textual).